How can I interpret the description part in POTCAR of VASP
I am studying the POTCAR file and I have a question.
There is an atomic arrangement in front of the POTCAR file.
I know that this part is different depending on the number of electrons in the electron band of the atom.
For oxygen, there are 4 electrons in the entry.
But below that, there are 5 electrons in the description.
Why are the number of electrons different in the entry and the description?
Atomic configuration 
 4 entries 
 n  l    j        E        occ. 
 1  0   0.50  -514.6923   2.0000
 2  0   0.50   -23.9615   2.0000
 2  1   0.50    -9.0305   4.0000
 3  2   1.50    -9.5241   0.0000
Description
l       E         TYP  RCUT  TYP RCUT
0   -23.9615318    23  1.200
0    -9.5240782    23  1.200
1    -9.0304911    23  1.520
1     8.1634956    23  1.520
2    -9.5240782     7  1.500


+1. Welcome to our community.

Could you add the file content inside a code block, please?

Thanks for the greeting.
I fixed it!
This is part of the oxygen POTCAR file.
As you can see, there are 4 electrons in the atomic component. And those are the atomic value electrons.
But below that, it says 5 electrons.
So I wonder why one electron is added.

The number of electons is not 4 neither 5, you should count the numbers in the occ. column, which is in the case of neutral oxygen 8.
According to VASP documentation, The first three columns are n, l, and j which stands for the principal, angular momentum, total angular momentum j=|l+s| quantum numbers, while E is the energy level of that state (in eV), last one is occ. is the occupation number (number of electrons in that state). These entries describe the electronic structure of the atom, indicating which orbitals are considered in the pseudopotential generation.
To my understanding, the first entry should be 1s orbital with energy −514.6923 eV, fully occupied with 2 electrons. While, the third entry is 2p orbital with energy −9.0305 eV, occupied with 4 electrons.
If I am not mistaken, the second section (Description) is supposed to be related  to projectors and augmentation functions, so the first two rows should be related to the s orbitals, the other two for p, and the last for d orbitals. RCUT should be cutoff radius (Å) for the projection or augmentation function. I am not sure what TYP stands for, it could be the type!

Thanks for the answer.
I have one more question.
Oxygen electrons are 1s2 2s2 2p4.
So d orbital electrons do not exist in oxygen.
But in the explanation part, it seems like d orbital electrons exist.
How can I understand this?

That looks like a new question, maybe you could ask a new question specifically about that.

@PIXEL please ask each new question as a new post, rather than in comments. This makes it more practical for you to get an answer.
